# Using Excel, Based On One Column Input, Receive Specific Response Other Column ... Improvements?

Tags: excel, select, filter, case

Can this code be improved ? I'm using a SELECT CASE statement to filter input terms resulting in a matched term. Thank you.

`Option Explicit`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Long
For r = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Select Case Cells(r, "I").Value
        Case "Marketing"
            Cells(r, 11).Value = "John Smith"
        Case "Desktop Support"
            Cells(r, 11).Value = "Jane Doe"
        Case Else
            Cells(r, 11).Value = "Not Defined"
    End Select
Next
```

End Sub

[image: SELECT CASE]

Comment: Is there are reason you are not doing this with a formula?

Comment: There are a large number of TEAM LEADERS.

Comment: So? A lookup table would be able to handle hundreds of departments/team leaders

Comment: Provide an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lookup table with all the input and output terms:

[image]

Use the following formula to lookup the values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(J$2:J$3,MATCH(A2,I$2:I$3,0),1),"Not Defined")
```

[image]